# How to change background color of status bar but not that of navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, statusbar

RootVc:
[image]

PushVc:
[image]

How to implement this effect?

How to change the background color of the status bar but not that of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your every viewcontroller, or (Call it from category method)

```
-(void)status_bar_color
{
      if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
      {
            UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            if(result.height >750)
            {
                  addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 23);
            }
            else if(result.height >550)//IPod
            {
                  addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 23);
            }
            else
            {
                  addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 23);
            }

            addStatusBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            [self.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
      }
}
```

For the light content of statusbar, use this method also,

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
      return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Cool..

Comment: this is not good,RootVc navigation is hidden add subview is ok,but PushVc is not good

Comment: I there any way to change it for pushvc? In my project i chosen every viewcontroller as model so it suits for me.

Answer (score 0):

set `View controller-based status bar appearance` is `NO` . in your project info.plist.and from Project setting Your can change status bar bG color as per your requirement

i have one suggestion please change windows BG color and set Status bar `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`
Add below code in appdelegate.m  :

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor <yourColor>];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Comment: I didn't find modify the status bar color attributes

Comment: ohh sorry did you mean you want status bar BG color apart from light gray and black color ? if YES then please see my edited answer

Comment: I have already got the answer~Thank you very much for your answer ~

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code Which I use to change status bar color or background.

```
     if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        {
            UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
     view.backgroundColor=[UIColor YourColorName];

If you wanted to add image you can use the line given below.  
/*
            view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbackground.png"]];
            [self.view addSubview:view];
*/        
}
```

Try this if I don't work , Please let me know.